# React JS Jest mock implementation of Class with static members

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, class, static-methods

I am working on a project in which I am writing jest unit testing but I am stuck with below problem. I also search on google but not get any proper solution.

### ActivityDetailsModal.js

```
class ActivityDetailsModal {
    static Activity = {
        activityType : ‘PLOT’
    }
}
```

### Xyz.test.js

```
Import { ActivityDetailsModal, useCustomHook } from ‘@cc-module’;

// This mock being used in other test case
jest.mock(‘@cc-module’,() => ({
    useCustomHook : jest.fn();
}));

it('should fail test’, async () => {
    …..
    // Here I get the error : ActivityDetailsModal is undefined
    const activityType = ActivityDetailsModal.Activity.activityType;
    …..
});
```

So I think because of mock implementation of `@cc-module` I am unable to access `ActivityDetailsModal` here So how can I have mock implementation of this class or some how I can ignore mocking for one particular test. I don’t know how is this possible.

Comment: yes I export `ActivityDetailsModal` and Everything static inside it so I also update my question.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
jest.mock('@cc-module', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('@cc-module'),
   useCustomHook : jest.fn();
}));
```

if you only want to mock the `useCustomHook`